# How to pass a list to psql on command line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, postgresql

I'd like to know if there's a way do so something like this :

```
lab-2:/tmp# echo  46692,46694,46696,46704,46708,46709,46713,46730,46736,46574 > deletelist.txt
lab-2:/tmp# cat deletelist.txt
46692,46694,46696,46704,46708,46709,46713,46730,46736,46574
```

And then I'd like to pass the list into a delete command via psql.  So far, this is what I tried but as you can see it's failing:

```
   lab-2:/tmp# psql -U test testdb -c "Delete from widgets where id in (" <deletelist.txt ")"
    psql: warning: extra command-line argument ")" ignored
    ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
    LINE 1: Delete from mist_cdr where id in (
                                          ^
```

**EDIT 1**

Attempting the suggested answer gives the following results:

```
lab-2:/tmp# psql -U test testdb -c "delete from widgets where id in ( $(</tmp/deletelist.txt ))"
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: delete from widgets where id in ( )
                                           ^
lab-2:/tmp#
```

Also tried the same command without the path, like so:

```
lab-2:/tmp# psql -U test testdb -c "delete from widgets where id in ( $(<deletelist.txt ))"
```

but same results

Comment: just wondering why i got dinged for this question?  poorly worded?  bad question?  I'm afraid i'm no good with bash and didn't know what keywords to google

Answer (score 1):

Try to use within command substitution.

```
psql -U test testdb -c "Delete from widgets where id in ( $(<deletelist.txt) )"
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.  will update my question with results

Comment: Would you add a semicolon at the end of the statement and check if that works?